# Unable to make a ajax call in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Am trying to send the value of load to a controller but its not working and i dunno why. Here is what i am doing. Can anyone point out what i am doing wrong ??

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var load = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
    load++;

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'get-response',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                "load" = load;
            },
            success: function(response){

                //handling the response
            }
        });
}
});
});
```

So according to the script each time i scroll to the bottom of the page the ajax must send the value of load, but nothing seems to be happening. Nothing happens under Network tab

Answer (score 3):

try to change from

```
"load" = load;
```

to

```
"load": load
```

Comment: yes looks like the ajax call is being made now :) but getting a 500 internal server error. I guess i 'll have to handle the response properly. Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

The **dataType** parameter determines the datatype of response object, & not that of the data sent.The **contentType** parameter determines the type of data sent.Here's an example of ajax call.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'get-response',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: {
            load: "load"
        },
        success: function(response){

            //handling the response
        }
    });
```

You can read full documentation here [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Also refer how to properly set 'response' value in your servlet,otherwise your ajax call wont be successful.